Fix Incorrect EU Trader Status in Google Play Console
In the Google Play Console, a while ago someone at my company marked our EU Trader Status as "Not Trader", but we in fact do qualify as a trader. How do I go back and change this? I've searched all over and found no answer. I also tried contacting Google support, but their support chat gave me an error and stopped working.
How do I change our EU Trader Status after one has already been submitted?
